# Python 3 in Enthought Canopy

Tags: python-3.x, enthought, canopy

How to use Python 3 in Canopy Enthought? It has the option on the bottom to select Python 3, but this does not change anything when we use:

```
print(sys.version)
2.7.3 | 32-bit | (default, Mar 25 2013, 15:38:39) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Comment: `$ python3 myscript.py` is a specific command to call the script with if you still have 2.7 on your system too.

Comment: This does not work within Enthought. The issue is that I cannot build numpy for python 3.3 on this organization's computer. Canopy Enthought works, but my script was written in 3.3.

Comment: I came here to ask this very same question. There's no way to use Python 3 within Canopy then?

Comment: @Juanlu001 I gave up on it... The reason I wanted to use it was because I couldn't get Python 3.3 to work in the environment. Since I fixed it there, it became obsolete to my cause.

Comment: I started a bounty because for me it's important to use Python 3 within Canopy. I'd like to have an answer, even if it is "Nope, you can't".

Comment: @Juanlu001 Best bet would be to email them and ask. Perhaps if you're a subscribed/paying member there's an option.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm "only" an academic user, but yes, I will email them and see. EDIT: Already submitted ticket, waiting.

Comment: BTW I think the dropdown menu that you mention is just syntax highlight.

Comment: @Dualinity are you willing to accept that as the good answer? I don't think there is other option as of today :/

Comment: @Dualinity Your question seems to have been answered, why not accept it?

Comment: @user417896 Forgotten about it.

Comment: I keep on getting upvotes for this. My personal recommendation: go for Anaconda. https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An Enthought engineer answered that at present **it is not possible to use Python 3 in or with Canopy**. They are considering several ways to support it but none of them will arrive in the short term.

**Edit**: [Enthought just announced Python 3 support for Canopy 2.0](http://blog.enthought.com/canopy/new-year-new-enthought-python-products/).

Comment: +1 for the heads up (and the legwork), this could be a critical issue for many.

Answer (score 0):

as you can see on https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/ *most(or some)* packages which Canopy uses are only **python-2.x** compatible therefore in which case if you are trying to use a outdated module within Canopy this causes Canopy to in-stabilize and **thus ends up not working in a python 3.x environment**

Answer (score 0):

Canopy now supports not only Python 3 but switching between multiple Python 2.7 and 3.x environments.

From the knowledge base article:
"In Canopy 2.1, internet-connected users (and all users of the Enthought Deployment Server) can create, manage, and switch between multiple Python 2.7 and 3.5 environments, with different environments containing different package sets. When you switch to a particular Python environment in Canopy 2.1, it is used throughout Canopy -- in the Package Manager, Editor, Python panel, Debugger, Data Import Tool, Jupyter Notebook, and Canopy Command Prompt / Terminal."

https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002376586-Canopy-2-1-Managing-and-switching-between-Python-2-7-and-3-5-environments

Comment: "not only" as if they did a good job.... we're talking 5 years later ;)