# Why does the Canopy Python3 IDE return quotes around text when using print function?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, enthought, canopy

I am trying to simply print text in Canopy and here is what's going on.

Input:

```
k = 3
Print ('Candidate =',k)
```

Output:

```
('Candidate =', 3)
```

Why are the parenthesis and quotations in the output? I just want it to print: `Candidate = 3`

Comment: Why did you just unaccept my answer?

Comment: I wish I could delete my noob questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2, `print` is a statement. As a statement, parentheses are *not* part of the syntax for it (just like with `return`). So when Python sees `print (a, b)`, it will parse the `(a, b)` part separately. And for the parser, this is a tuple:

```
value = ('Candidate =', k)
print value
```

When you print a tuple, it will print parentheses, and inside, a list of all values—with their `repr` value. And a string’s repr value, is enquoted:

```
>>> print repr('Candidate =')
'Candidate ='
```

So, to get the result you want, you need to pass `'Candidate ='` and `k` to the print statement, without putting it in a tuple. So you just need to remove the parentheses:

```
>>> print 'Candidate =', k
Candidate = 3
```

Note that in Python 3, `print` became a function, so it actually *requires* parentheses and your original code works like you wanted it. If you want the print *function* in Python 2 (instead of print being a statement), you can put the following at the top of your code, to make it so:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Canopy seems to come with its own Python 2 environment, so it doesn’t use whatever you have installed. And according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142764/python-3-3-in-enthought-canopy), there seems to be no support for Python 3 in Canopy.

Comment: Exactly. Canopy *is* a complete Python 2.7 scientific distribution which includes an IDE. It is not an IDE installable into your existing Python distribution, whether Python 2.x or 3.x